# Project management tools for v-model?

Tags: project-management

My boss worked for a big company where V-model  and Rational Notes are used.

Now I am working for him and he really don't like TRAC which I am using.  For him, it's too simple, it has no idea of a "project", it doesn't have clear separations of "Requirement analysis -> System Design -> ..."

So he asked me to find some new tools, which could integrate requirement management, bug tracking, task tracking, and could force a V-model in the developement process.

I looked for a couple of open-source project management tools and I can find anything similar.    It seems that V-model is not so popular in open source model.  And we can not use Rational Notes because it's really expensive.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The V-model (admittedly, I had seen it before but didn't know its name) is more closely associated with Waterfall as opposed to any of the Agile methods... so you're going to have a hard time finding Open Source tools that support it.  Which makes sense... OSS is developed as Agile due to a constant flow of requirements and feature requests balanced against limited time and everyone scratching their personal itch.

I think you're going to have difficulties unless you roll your own...

Answer (score 0):

Try Rational Software Architect

Comment: The licences for RSA are on a par with the other Rational tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Lighthouse](http://www.artifactsoftware.com/products/Requirements-Management.html?ghtoolsrm).  They offer a free (as in free beer) basic hosted service for a single small project, or you can pay for a more-featured edition.